# Move Triangle Shape Within Range

Tags: excel, vba, ms-office

[image: Click here to see image]

I hope someone can help me!

I want that when I enter a value in cell B3 (or B4), the triangle in cell F3 (or J4) moves along. Likewise, when I enter a value in cell C3 (or C4), the triangle in cell J3 (or Q4) will also move. How to program when I have many TASK to do. Thanks.

Comment: Try using the [`Worksheet.Change`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change) event.

Comment: But I've only been learning vba for 1 day. Can you help me??

Answer (score 5):

What you want can be achieved using a Line Chart. No VBA is required.

Here is a basic example.

**Disclaimer**: This is a very basic example. You will have to modify this to suit your needs.

Let's say you have the dates as shown below in a worksheet.

[image]

**Follow these steps**

**1.** Enter `1` in the cells `G2:L2`

[image]

**2.** Select cells `G2:L2`. Click on `Insert` tab and insert a Line Chart

[image]

**3.** Delete the gridlines, chart title and the axes of the chart by selecting it.

[image]

**4.** Set the fill as `No Fill` and border as `No Line`

[image]

**5.** Select the line and set the marker properties as shown below

[image]

**6.** Right click on the chart and click on `Select Data`

[image]

**7.** Click on `Hidden and Empty cells`

[image]

**8.** Select the options as shown in the below dialog box. Click on `OK`. Click on `OK` again to close the 2nd dialog box

[image]

**9.** Enter the formula `=IFERROR(MATCH(G1,$B$2,0),NA())` in cell `G2`

**10.** Enter the formula `=IFERROR(MATCH(H1,$B$3,0),NA())` in cell `H2` and copy it to the last cell. In our case it is `L2`. Your worksheet will look like this

[image]

**11.** Change the font color of the cells `G2:L2` to white

[image]

**12.** Next enter a start date and the end date. You will notice the line

[image]

**13.** Do the basic formatting and adjust the chart so that the markers are in the center of the cell.

[image]

And you are done.

**IN ACTION**

[image]

Comment: So freaking cool! I saved the answer for future use!

Answer (score 1):

Okay Admittedly this turned out to be a bit of a mess of a script... but it works.

- Make sure to name all your shapes!!!
- Make sure all the ranges I reference are the same ranges you reference. (easy to fix)

Here is is, make SURE this goes in your worksheet module:
[image]
(Or whatever sheet you're using)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim oTri As Object      'Triangle Object
    Dim oLine As Object     'Line Object
    Dim tLeft As Long       'Left as an integer
    Dim tCell As Range      'Found Value Cell as range
    
    'Used to decide which triangle needs to be updated.
    Select Case Target.Address
        Case "$B$3"     'Design Mode Start Day
            Set oTri = Shapes("LTopTri")
            Set oLine = Shapes("TopLine")
        Case "$C$3"     'Design Mode Finish Day
            Set oTri = Shapes("RTopTri")
            Set oLine = Shapes("TopLine")
        Case "$B$4"     'Manufacture Start Day
            Set oTri = Shapes("LBottomTri")
            Set oLine = Shapes("BottomLine")
        Case "$C$4"     'Manufacture Finish Day
            Set oTri = Shapes("RBottomTri")
            Set oLine = Shapes("BottomLine")
        Case Else
            Exit Sub
    End Select
    
    'Move triangle & Line
    Set tCell = Cells(2, WorksheetFunction.Match(Day(Target.Value), Range("F2:S2")) + 5)
    tLeft = tCell.Left + (0.5 * tCell.Width)
    oTri.Top = Target.Top + (0.5 * Target.Height) - (0.5 * oTri.Height)
    oTri.Left = tLeft - (0.5 * oTri.Width)
    oLine.Top = oTri.Top + oTri.Height
    Select Case Target.Row
        Case "3"
            oLine.Left = Shapes("LTopTri").Left + (0.5 * Shapes("LTopTri").Width)
            oLine.Width = Shapes("RTopTri").Left - Shapes("LTopTri").Left
        Case "4"
            oLine.Left = Shapes("LBottomTri").Left + (0.5 * Shapes("LBottomTri").Width)
            oLine.Width = Shapes("RBottomTri").Left - Shapes("LBottomTri").Left
    End Select
    
End Sub
```

Shape Names:
[image]

Result Examples:
[image: EX1]
[image: EX2]
[image: EX3]
[image: EX4]

Comment: Oh, thank you so much. It's great. But I want to now that if I have 10 or 50 TASKS to do. There will be many triangles.  How can you program?

Comment: Okay, I posted a second answer that's better suited to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, if you intend on building this to accommodate ANY size of data. I would 100% recommend you use conditional formatting.

- First Step is the day row needs to be filled with full dates (you can do it without, this is just a bit easier). you can format them to just look like the DAY(date) but keep the full date in the cell:
  [image]
- Next, you're going to fill ALL THE CELLS in your scheduling chart area with this symbol: ▼:
  [image]
- Next you're going to Select ALL the little triangles, and format them white:
  [image]
  And they're all White:
  [image]
- Next, Add conditional Formatting. It will check if it is the start date or the end date:

> =OR($B2=E$1,$C2=E$1)

[image]

If you want to make this a bit easier to follow, we can add an additional layer of highlighting:
[image]
[image]
You WILL need to edit the previous formatting to include the blue, and also put it on top, but we're getting somewhere.

You can also add some lines with dashes:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Since you don't know the size of your given data set, this is great because you can scale it up and down as much as you want.

Comment: So there's no other way? Because if I did it this way, I would break my company's rules.

Comment: What? What kind of rules? I've never heard of a company that would prefer tools get built in VBA rather than conditional formatting.

Comment: If it **ABSOLUTELY MUST** be VBA, I can think of two ways to do it. 1) delete all shapes and build new ones everytime triggered... Especially if it's referencing a calculation event, That's going to make is slow.

Comment: 2) you could check all the shapes locations, and only change those in your updated range. It would be quite scalable and I'm guessing faster, but it might be a bit of code.

Answer (score 1):

if:

- you place your triangle properly
  i.e. taking care to have their TopLeftCell in the proper row
- add a "days" named range to encompass your "F2:S2" range

then you can use the following code to be place in the relevant
worksheet code pane:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    On Error GoTo SafeExit
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    With Target
        Select Case True

            Case .Column = 2
                MoveTriangle .Value, Target, True

            Case .Column = 3
                MoveTriangle .Value, Target, False

        End Select
    End With

SafeExit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub


Sub MoveTriangle(myDate As Date, Target As Range, OkStartTriangle As Long)
    
        Dim dateRng As Range
        Dim triangleShp As Shape
            Select Case True
            
                Case Not GetDate(myDate, Range("days"), _
                                 dateRng)
                    MsgBox "Couldn't find date '" & myDate & "' in '" & Range("days").Address(False, False) & "'"
                
                Case Not GetShape(Target.Row, OkStartTriangle, _
                                  triangleShp)
                    MsgBox "Couldn't find the " & IIf(OkStartTriangle, "starting", "ending") & " triangle for row: " & Target.Row
                
                Case Else
                    With triangleShp
                        .Left = dateRng.Left + 0.5 * (dateRng.Width - .Width)
                    End With
                
            End Select

End Sub

Function GetDate(myDate As Date, daysRng As Range, _
                 rng As Range) As Boolean
    Set rng = Range("days").Find(What:=myDate, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        GetDate = Not rng Is Nothing
End Function

Function GetShape(rowIndex As Long, OkStartTriangle As Long, _
                  triangleShp As Shape) As Boolean
    
    Dim triangleColumnIndex As Long
        If OkStartTriangle Then
            triangleColumnIndex = Columns.Count
        Else
            triangleColumnIndex = 0
        End If
    
            Set triangleShp = Nothing
            
            Dim shp As Shape
                For Each shp In Shapes
                    With shp
                        With .TopLeftCell
                            Select Case True
                                Case .Row <> rowIndex
                                
                                Case OkStartTriangle
                                    
                                    If .Column < triangleColumnIndex Then
                                        triangleColumnIndex = .Column
                                        Set triangleShp = shp
                                    End If
                            
                                Case Else
                                    
                                    If .Column > triangleColumnIndex Then
                                        triangleColumnIndex = .Column
                                        Set triangleShp = shp
                                    End If
                            
                            End Select
                        End With
                    End With
                Next
                
                    GetShape = Not triangleShp Is Nothing                    

End Function
```

Comment: @BuiTao did you try this?

Comment: You’re welcome. And you might then want to accept this answer as the solution. Thank you

Comment: @BuiTao, what made you remove the acceptance of this solution?